# Change local branch to master and update remote master

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I have

1. Production server (Which I want it to be connected to master branch)
2. Staging server( Which is connected to staging branch under the same git repo)

I copied the staging files and placed under production server and made some changes/deleted some files.

Now under the production server when I do `git status` it shows I am under staging local branch. Next when I do `git checkout master` then it says to commit or stash the work done on local otherwise it will be overwritten before I can switch the branch from staging to master.

I want to merge the local master branch with local staging branch and then update the remote master branch.

Please any hint/help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do what the git says.

Either commit the changes and then resolve any merge conflicts if any one by one.

Or stash the changes `git stash` and the after checking out the master apply the stash
`git stash apply` and then resolve any merge conflicts if any one by one.

Make sure to keep a copy of your locally changed files(The ones git asked you to commit or stash) elsewhere if are not confident, so that you can retrieve the current state later if some thing gets messed up.

Comment: Thank you. Actually local master branch has not been updated for years and I deleted the master branch and then `git checkout -b master` and then pushed commit to remote master.